# Should you use arguments in the view?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to figure out a best practice for MVC. Should I 
 1. Create a function in the model that takes in an argument? (And then provide that argument in the view) 
 2. Create a function in the model that DOES NOT take an argument. Instead pass in the value that I need within the model itself

This is an example of #1. Note that this is inside my view.

```
// this selects the desired food id 
$food_id = favfoods::model()->selectedfav();
// this then uses that selected foodid as an argument to the function favpeople 
$people = People::model()->favpeople($food_id);
```

This is an example of #2. Note that this is inside the model, and that the function favpeople no longer takes an argument.

```
public function favpeople() 
    {
        // this gets the necessary food_id.
        $food_id = favfoods::model()->selectedfav(); 

        // This selects the id of the person who matches the "food_id"
        $favpeeps = 'SELECT personid FROM people WHERE food_id = "'.$food_id.'"';

        // This implements the query.
        $result=yii::app()->db->createCommand($favpeeps)->queryAll();

        // The result is an array, so I loop through the array to return the personid that I want. 
        foreach($result as $count)
        {

            return $count['personid'];
        }
    }
```

Which is better practice 1. Calling two functions in the view and having one of the functions be the argument of the other. Or 2. Do the dirty work of using arguments in advance in the model?

Comment: Have you considered using `limit 1` in your query?

Comment: This is not MVC. Also, `foreach { return }`? Also, `echo $a = ...`? A lot of redundant/plain wrong code here. Could you please clear up your question? Right now I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: .. also, your SQL is vulnerable to injections.

Comment: Okay, I just edited up the question - I hope that makes it more clear. And thank you Teresko and Marek for the suggestions - highly appreciated.

Comment: You should never have logic in a view. Selecting something from the database, even if encapsulated in an ORM, is logic. In a week from now you'll find out you need a `where` condition on that select. What should you do then? Extract it in the controller. As a side note: that select should not even be in a controller. It should be in a service, abstracting data access from the controller so that if your data model changes the controller does not have to.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv , to clarify you are saying that I should not even be calling the line $people = People::model()->favpeople($food_id);  in the view? Instead I should be calling that line in the controller?

Comment: Yes. The actual SQL query is executed in that line.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this. You also said that it would be best that People::model()->favpeople(); should even be extracted into a service (which I looked into). So, that if in the future my code changes in the future - then I don't need to change the controller?